# How to parser JSON and add some custom strings?

Tags: json, raku

I have a JSON which come from spark:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://xxx-namespace/20190311")
val jsonStr = df.schema.json
```

`jsonStr` is like this:

```
{
    "type":"struct",
    "fields":[
        {
            "name":"alm_dm_list",
            "type":{
                "type":"array",
                "elementType":"integer",
                "containsNull":true
            },
            "nullable":true,
            "metadata":{

            }
        },
        {
            "name":"data_batt_sc_volt_lowest",
            "type":"double",
            "nullable":true,
            "metadata":{

            }
        },
        {
            "name":"veh_dcdcst",
            "type":"integer",
            "nullable":true,
            "metadata":{

            }
        },
        {
            "name":"esd_temp_data",
            "type":{
                "type":"array",
                "elementType":{
                    "type":"struct",
                    "fields":[
                        {
                            "name":"esd_temp_probe_cnt",
                            "type":"integer",
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"esd_temp_probe_list",
                            "type":{
                                "type":"array",
                                "elementType":"integer",
                                "containsNull":true
                            },
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"esd_temp_subsys_seq",
                            "type":"integer",
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "containsNull":true
            },
            "nullable":true,
            "metadata":{

            }
        },
        {
            "name":"esd_volt_data",
            "type":{
                "type":"array",
                "elementType":{
                    "type":"struct",
                    "fields":[
                        {
                            "name":"esd_curr",
                            "type":"double",
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"esd_frame_sc_cnt",
                            "type":"integer",
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"esd_frame_sc_list",
                            "type":{
                                "type":"array",
                                "elementType":"double",
                                "containsNull":true
                            },
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"esd_frame_start",
                            "type":"integer",
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"esd_sc_cnt",
                            "type":"integer",
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"esd_volt",
                            "type":"double",
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"esd_volt_subsys_seq",
                            "type":"integer",
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "containsNull":true
            },
            "nullable":true,
            "metadata":{

            }
        },
        {
            "name":"dm_data",
            "type":{
                "type":"array",
                "elementType":{
                    "type":"struct",
                    "fields":[
                        {
                            "name":"dm_ctl_dc_curr",
                            "type":"double",
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"dm_ctl_temp",
                            "type":"integer",
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"dm_ctl_volt",
                            "type":"double",
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"dm_seq",
                            "type":"integer",
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"dm_spd",
                            "type":"integer",
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"dm_st",
                            "type":"integer",
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"dm_temp",
                            "type":"integer",
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"dm_torq",
                            "type":"integer",
                            "nullable":true,
                            "metadata":{

                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "containsNull":true
            },
            "nullable":true,
            "metadata":{

            }
        }]
}
```

I want to get a scheme based on the JSON string, so i need to parse it and get a struct like this:

```
  val schema = new StructType()
    .add("alm_dm_list", ArrayType(IntegerType, true), true)
    .add("data_batt_sc_volt_lowest", DoubleType, true)
    .add("veh_dcdcst", IntegerType, true)
    .add("esd_temp_data", ArrayType(new StructType()
      .add("esd_temp_probe_cnt", IntegerType, true)
      .add("esd_temp_probe_list", ArrayType(IntegerType, true), true)
      .add("esd_temp_subsys_seq", IntegerType, true)
    ), true)
    .add("esd_volt_data", ArrayType(new StructType()
      .add("esd_curr", DoubleType, true)
      .add("esd_frame_sc_cnt", IntegerType, true)
      .add("esd_frame_sc_list", ArrayType(DoubleType, true), true)
      .add("esd_frame_start", IntegerType, true)
      .add("esd_sc_cnt", IntegerType, true)
      .add("esd_volt", DoubleType, true)
      .add("esd_volt_subsys_seq", IntegerType, true)
    ), true)
    .add("dm_data", ArrayType(new StructType()
      .add("dm_ctl_dc_curr", DoubleType, true)
      .add("dm_ctl_temp", IntegerType, true)
      .add("dm_ctl_volt", DoubleType, true)
      .add("dm_seq", IntegerType, true)
      .add("dm_spd", IntegerType, true)
      .add("dm_st", IntegerType, true)
      .add("dm_temp", IntegerType, true)
      .add("dm_torq", IntegerType, true)
    ), true)
```

[JSON::Infer](https://github.com/jonathanstowe/JSON-Infer) maybe helpful, but there are nested structures in my JSON, which is complex for me, any suggestions will help.

Comment: Have you looked at [JSON::Class](https://modules.perl6.org/dist/JSON::Class:cpan:JSTOWE) it might be able to do what you want.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to create a Perl 6 script that produces SPARK code based on a JSON input file?

Comment: @Scimon Thank you, I'll post the solution here if i figure it out.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland Yes, just to produce a schema that can be used by Spark. Because the JSON is not always  the same, so i have to write the `schema` by hand, which may make mistake.

Answer (score 2):

In case you do not care about identing (possible, but not so important, what about this ?) does not work in IE - guess template strings are only problem(?):

```js
'use strict';

function run() {
 buildRecursive(2);
 res = res.substr(0, res.length-1) + ';';
 console.log(res);
}

var typeRename = {
 "array": "ArrayType",
 "double": "DoubleType",
 "integer": "IntegerType"
}, elementRename = {
 "integer": "IntegerType",
 "double": "DoubleType"
}
var res = "val schema = ";

function repeatIndent(no) {
    var retVal = '';
    while(no--) retVal += ' ';
    return retVal;
}

function buildRow(indent, params) {
    return repeatIndent(indent) + params.join('');
}

function buildRecursive(indent) {
 var lev = it.ReadArray(), indentStep = 1;
 if(lev.type == "struct") {
  res += "new StructType()\n";
  var under = lev.fields;
  while(under && under.node) {
   it.SetCurrent(under.node);
   buildRecursive(indent + indentStep);
   under = under.next;
  }
 } else if (lev.name) {
  if(lev.type instanceof JNode) {
   it.SetCurrent(lev.type.node);
   var lev2 = it.ReadArray();
   it.DepthFirst();
   var elementType = it.FindKey("elementType");
   if(elementType.value instanceof Object) {
                res += buildRow(indent, ['.add("', lev.name, '", ', typeRename[lev2.type], '(']);
    var here = it.Current;
    it.SetCurrent(elementType.node);
    buildRecursive(indent + indentStep);
    it.SetCurrent(here);
    res += buildRow(indent,['), ', lev.nullable, ')\n']);
            } else res += buildRow(indent, ['.add("', lev.name, '", ', typeRename[lev2.type], '(',
                    elementRename[elementType.value], ', ', lev2.containsNull, '), ', lev.nullable, ')\n']);
  } else {
   res += buildRow(indent, ['.add("', lev.name, '", ', typeRename[lev.type], ', ', lev.nullable, ')\n']);
  }
 }
}

// My JSON iterator
var JNode = (function (jsNode) {
    
 function JNode(_parent, _pred, _key, _value) {
  this.parent = _parent;
  this.pred = _pred;
  this.node = null;
  this.next = null;
  this.key = _key;
  this.value = _value;
 }

 return JNode;
})();
var JIterator = (function (json) {
 var root, current, maxLevel = -1;

 function JIterator(json, parent) {
  if (parent === undefined) parent = null;
  var pred = null, localCurrent;
  for (var child in json) {
   var obj = json[child] instanceof Object;
   if(json instanceof Array) child = parseInt(child); // non-associative array
   if (!root) root = localCurrent = new JNode(parent, null, child, json[child]);
   else {
    localCurrent = new JNode(parent, pred, child, obj ? ((json[child] instanceof Array) ? [] : {}) : json[child]);
   }
   if (pred) pred.next = localCurrent;
   if (parent && parent.node == null) parent.node = localCurrent;
   pred = localCurrent;
   if (obj) {
    var memPred = pred;
    JIterator(json[child], pred);
    pred = memPred;
   }
  }
  if (this) {
   current = root;
   this.Level = 0;
  }
 }

 JIterator.prototype.Current = function () { return current; }
 JIterator.prototype.SetCurrent = function (newCurrent) { current = newCurrent; }
 JIterator.prototype.Parent = function () {
  var retVal = current.parent;
  if (retVal == null) return false;
  this.Level--;
  return current = retVal;
 }
 JIterator.prototype.Pred = function () {
  var retVal = current.pred;
  if (retVal == null) return false;
  return current = retVal;
 }
 JIterator.prototype.Node = function () {
  var retVal = current.node;
  if (retVal == null) return false;
  this.Level++;
  return current = retVal;
 }
 JIterator.prototype.Next = function () {
  var retVal = current.next;
  if (retVal == null) return false;
  return current = retVal;
 }
 JIterator.prototype.Key = function () { return current.key; }
 JIterator.prototype.KeyDots = function () { return (typeof(current.key) == "number")?"":(current.key+':'); }
 JIterator.prototype.Value = function () { return current.value; }
 JIterator.prototype.Reset = function () {
  current = root;
  this.Level = 0;
 }
 JIterator.prototype.RawPath = function () {
  var steps = [], level = current;
  do {
   if (level != null && level.value instanceof Object) {
    steps.push(level.key + (level.value instanceof Array ? "[]" : "{}"));
   } else {
    if (level != null) steps.push(level.key);
    else break;
   }
   level = level.parent;
  } while (level != null);
  var retVal = "";
  retVal = steps.reverse();
  return retVal;
 }
 JIterator.prototype.Path = function () {
  var steps = [], level = current;
  do {
   if (level != null && level.value instanceof Object) {
    var size = 0;
    var items = level.node;
    if(typeof(level.key) == "number") steps.push('[' + level.key + ']');
    else {
     while(items) {
      size++;
      items = items.next;
     }
     var type = (level.value instanceof Array ? "[]" : "{}");
     var prev = steps[steps.length-1];
     if(prev && prev[0] == '[') {
      var last = prev.length-1;
      if(prev[last] == ']') {
       last--;
       if(!isNaN(prev.substr(1, last))) {
        steps.pop();
        size += '.' + prev.substr(1, last);
       }
      }
     }
     steps.push(level.key + type[0] + size + type[1]);
    }
   } else {
    if (level != null) {
     if(typeof(level.key) == "number") steps.push('[' + level.key + ']');
     else steps.push(level.key);
    }
    else break;
   }
   level = level.parent;
  } while (level != null);
  var retVal = "";
  retVal = steps.reverse();
  return retVal;
 }
 JIterator.prototype.DepthFirst = function () {
  if (current == null) return 0; // exit sign
  if (current.node != null) {
   current = current.node;
   this.Level++;
   if (maxLevel < this.Level) maxLevel = this.Level;
   return 1; // moved down
  } else if (current.next != null) {
   current = current.next;
   return 2; // moved right
  } else {
   while (current != null) {
    if (current.next != null) {
     current = current.next;
     return 3; // returned up & moved next
    }
    this.Level--;
    current = current.parent;
   }
  }
  return 0; // exit sign
 }
 JIterator.prototype.BreadthFirst = function () {
  if (current == null) return 0; // exit sign
  if (current.next) {
   current = current.next;
   return 1; // moved right
  } else if (current.parent) {
   var level = this.Level, point = current;
   while (this.DepthFirst() && level != this.Level);
   if (current) return 2; // returned up & moved next
   do {
    this.Reset();
    level++;
    while (this.DepthFirst() && level != this.Level);
    if (current) return 3; // returned up & moved next
   } while (maxLevel >= level);
   return current != null ? 3 : 0;
  } else if (current.node) {
   current = current.node;
   return 3;
  } else if (current.pred) {
   while (current.pred) current = current.pred;
   while (current && !current.node) current = current.next;
   if (!current) return null;
   else return this.DepthFirst();
  }
 }
 JIterator.prototype.ReadArray = function () {
  var retVal = {};
  var item = current;
  do {
   if(item.value instanceof Object) {
    if(item.value.length == 0) retVal[item.key] = item.node;
    else retVal[item.key] = item;
   } else retVal[item.key] = item.value;
   item = item.next;
  } while (item != null);
  return retVal;
 }
 JIterator.prototype.FindKey = function (key) {
  var pos = current;
  while(current && current.key != key) this.DepthFirst();
  if(current.key == key) {
   var retVal = current;
   current = pos;
   return retVal;
  } else {
   current = pos;
   return null;
  }
 }

 return JIterator;
})();

var json = {
 "type": "struct",
 "fields": [
  {
   "name": "alm_dm_list",
   "type": {
    "type": "array",
    "elementType": "integer",
    "containsNull": true
   },
   "nullable": true,
   "metadata": {}
  },
  {
   "name": "data_batt_sc_volt_lowest",
   "type": "double",
   "nullable": true,
   "metadata": {}
  },
  {
   "name": "veh_dcdcst",
   "type": "integer",
   "nullable": true,
   "metadata": {}
  },
  {
   "name": "esd_temp_data",
   "type": {
    "type": "array",
    "elementType": {
     "type": "struct",
     "fields": [
      {
       "name": "esd_temp_probe_cnt",
       "type": "integer",
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      },
      {
       "name": "esd_temp_probe_list",
       "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "elementType": "integer",
        "containsNull": true
       },
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      },
      {
       "name": "esd_temp_subsys_seq",
       "type": "integer",
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      }
     ]
    },
    "containsNull": true
   },
   "nullable": true,
   "metadata": {}
  },
  {
   "name": "esd_volt_data",
   "type": {
    "type": "array",
    "elementType": {
     "type": "struct",
     "fields": [
      {
       "name": "esd_curr",
       "type": "double",
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      },
      {
       "name": "esd_frame_sc_cnt",
       "type": "integer",
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      },
      {
       "name": "esd_frame_sc_list",
       "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "elementType": "double",
        "containsNull": true
       },
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      },
      {
       "name": "esd_frame_start",
       "type": "integer",
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      },
      {
       "name": "esd_sc_cnt",
       "type": "integer",
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      },
      {
       "name": "esd_volt",
       "type": "double",
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      },
      {
       "name": "esd_volt_subsys_seq",
       "type": "integer",
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      }
     ]
    },
    "containsNull": true
   },
   "nullable": true,
   "metadata": {}
  },
  {
   "name": "dm_data",
   "type": {
    "type": "array",
    "elementType": {
     "type": "struct",
     "fields": [
      {
       "name": "dm_ctl_dc_curr",
       "type": "double",
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      },
      {
       "name": "dm_ctl_temp",
       "type": "integer",
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      },
      {
       "name": "dm_ctl_volt",
       "type": "double",
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      },
      {
       "name": "dm_seq",
       "type": "integer",
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      },
      {
       "name": "dm_spd",
       "type": "integer",
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      },
      {
       "name": "dm_st",
       "type": "integer",
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      },
      {
       "name": "dm_temp",
       "type": "integer",
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      },
      {
       "name": "dm_torq",
       "type": "integer",
       "nullable": true,
       "metadata": {}
      }
     ]
    },
    "containsNull": true
   },
   "nullable": true,
   "metadata": {}
  }
 ]
};

var it = new JIterator(json);
run();
```